# Following the changing output of a command

Tags: bash, shell

I am using a status-querying command that returns the status of the batch jobs I currently have running. I would like to have a real-time feed of the changes in the output of this command, such as jobs moving from PEND to RUN or disappearing from the list entirely, basically a similar effect to "tail -f" on a log file.

Is there a simple *nix utility for this or do I have to write a script?

Comment: I am curious how `tail -f` does not do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [watch](http://ss64.com/bash/watch.html). It can highlight changes that occur between runs of the job whose output it monitors.